# SQL Function to print selected values

Tags: mysql

My database has a table with the following schema:

```
account(acno,amt)

acno int primary key
amt float(10,2)
```

How would I write a function that prints all account numbers having odd balance?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM account WHERE MOD(amt, .02) > 0;`

Should do the trick.

Doesn't really make sense to create function just to do what a simple query can do - that is, just output the rows that match your criteria. If you really need a function I guess you could make one to determine if a number is odd:

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_odd(amount float) RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
    DECLARE isodd BOOLEAN;
    SET isodd = TRUE;

    IF MOD(amount,.02) = 0 THEN
        SET isodd = FALSE;
    END IF;

 RETURN (isodd);
END
```

And then you can use this in the query instead:

`SELECT * FROM account where is_odd(amt);`

Comment: I need to write a function, not just a query.

Comment: Why must it be a function?

Comment: @wbrugato, shouldn't this be MOD(amount, .02) to account for the digits after the decimal?

Comment: good call, if you want to take into consideration the decimal @dazedandconfused has the correct logic. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This query return odd balance

```
SELECT acno, amt
  FROM 
  account
WHERE (amt % 2) > 0;
```